# Reusable controllers in FXML. One controller (slightly changed) for multiple fxml files

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I would like to know whether it is possible to "reuse" the controller for another fxml after creating it. In other words, can I create a controller for fxml, modify it a bit, and then use (another instance of) it for another fxml without affecting the first one. Otherwise, I am in a way forced to copy the code from the controller, apply the changes and then use the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see many use cases for this, as you will obviously have different controls in different FXML files, so it's not clear how you would manage injection. If you do have a use case (e.g. the different FXML files just have different layouts for the same basic UI), it is possible:

Remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML files, and set the controller manually using the following pattern:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/path/to/file.fxml"));
MyConfigurableController controller = new MyConfigurableController(aParam, anotherParam);
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have the following situation. I have two screens which change dynamically. In screen A I have a media bar and a controller for it. In screen B I would like to create a new media bar (the same but with a few more buttons for instance) and use the same controller but with the added functionality. Of course, I can hard copy the controller in a new one for the second media bar and use it for my purpose yet I was looking for more elegant solution such as adding a second controller to the newly created media bar which can handle the new stuff. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: @TheNephalem For that scenario, why wouldn't you just use inheritance?

Comment: I am so tired that I can hardly think anymore. Thank you very much you saved me a lot of time!